# Java web development without Eclipse

Tags: java

I'm interested in doing some Java web development but I'm not really interested in using Eclipse. I have used Eclipse in the past and to me it seems to add a layer of abstraction that I'm not really interested in. However, I'm having a bit of upstart problems.

Does anyone have any good references/tutorials in getting up and running with Java web development without using Eclipse (or any other IDE for that matter)?

Comment: My guess is that you will soon get interested in that "extra layer of abstraction"... Where exactly do you see the abstraction by the way? It is just automation, no?

Comment: Good comment. I have used Eclipse in the past and it seems that whenever I work with Eclipse and check out an older Java/Web project, nothing works anymore. Using no IDE and configuring things manually feels like like project will be more "transferable". If that makes sense..?

Comment: That does make sense. I say go with Maven to control your build, but use Eclipse for the IDE part. And learn what exactly happens during the build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a maven project and use one of the embedded web servers like jetty or Glassfish.

Also, this approach allows you to work with the command line directly or use either Netbeans, Eclipse or IntelliJ as your IDE as they support Maven projects.  I do not think that JDeveloper can yet.

(Eclipse may require the m2e plugin from the marketplace, and it handles all the Eclipse configuration transparently and directly.  Highly recommended).

Comment: But I am not sure if adding maven removes any abstraction.

Comment: Using Maven is an interesting idea. I haven't used Maven but I an willing to give it a go.

Comment: Use maven for your builds, and Eclipse to help you code. Maven has the "mvn eclipse:eclipse" target to build Eclipse artifacts based on the contents of your pom.xml.

Comment: @Jonathan these days the "m2e" plugin is much better than the "mvn eclipse:eclipse" command.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do java web development using notepad only. The extra work is, you have to write some extra code (like in servlet you have to write web.xml http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm). Same in Struts, Hibernate and Spring framework, you have to write config file in notepad.

Comment: Why is that extra code? You'd have to write that code in Eclipse as well.. Eclipse would just help you with it.

Comment: In case of servlet, you have to write entire web.xml in case if you're using notepad, but in case of IDE we have to edit only servlet class name. In case of Framework like hibernate, we have to write whole pojo class, but in case of IDE, we have to configure the beans name in IDE. same as in case of Struts and Spring framework,we have to write config file.